# Slick Carousel Slide Count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

I am using the slick carousel and trying to get the slide count. I am using React.js with ES6, below is the function I'm using to return the count but what I don't understand is that the console.log("inside" + n); prints the value whereas the one outside prints null, what am I doing wrong?

```
 countSlides() {
    let n = 0;
    $(this.innerSelector).on('init', (event, slick) => {
      n = slick.slideCount;
      console.log("inside" + n);
    });

    console.log("outside" + n);
    return n;

  }
```

I have created a class for the carousel so I can instantiate in different parent components. e.g for this one I have:

```
class ImageCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.carouselDidStart = false;
    this.carouselControl = new CarouselControl({
      outerSelector: ".carousel-container",
      innerSelector: ".extra-images-container",
      infinite: false
    });
  }
```

And then in the CarouselControl class I am trying to add this countSlides function so I can find the number of slides like this.carouselControl.countSlides();

Answer (score 0):

`$(this.innerSelector).on` is a event listener so it will be fired when the event fires so it's asynchronous function. You could do that same like:

```
 constructor() {
   this.slideCount = 0;
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   $(this.innerSelector).on('init', (event, slick) => {
    this.slideCount = slick.slideCount;
   });
 }

 countSlides() {
   return this.slideCount; 
 }
```

Comment: sorry this did n't work for me, so here is the thing I have made a class for slick carousel and I am instantiating it whichever component needs it, I'll update the question above..

Answer (score 0):

With the option row you can get the number of slides

```
$(this).slick("slickGetOption", "rows")
```